# Use a here string and lambda in a Sinatra helper method

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to create a Sinatra helper that returns a dynamically-generated HTML.  I thought I would use a here string for the static bit and a lambda to calculate the dynamic part.

`foo_helper.rb`:

```
require 'erb'
module FooHelper

  def tabs(selected)

    template = ERB.new <<~HERE
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <%= 'active' if selected == 'favorites' %>" href="/foo/favorites">Favorites</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <%= 'active' if selected == 'all' %>" href="/foo">All</a></li>
        <%= alpha.call %>
      </ul>
      HERE

    # binding to a string works as expected    
    # alpha = "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='/foo/a'>A</a></li>"

    # binding to a lambda, doesn't
    alpha = lambda {
      ('a'..'z').each do |letter|
        "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link #{ 'active' if selected == letter }' href='/foo/#{letter}'>#{letter}</a></li>"
      end
    }

    template.result(binding)

  end

end
```

`foo_controller.rb`:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  helpers FooHelper if defined?(FooHelper)
  ...
end
```

`index.erb`:

```
...
<%= tabs('favorites') %>
...
```

Results:

[image]

Displays the range, rather than the individual `li`s.

Am I missing something in the lambda?

** edit **

Corrected the numerous errors.

Comment: Unless there are things missing from your code that aren't shown above, ruby is NOT going to interpret @nav as an instance variable the way you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

There are just too many mistakes in your code.

1. `@nav` is defined at module level, but accessed at instance level, so you got `nil` when you need it.
2. When you call a lambda, you need a dot between the variable name and the opening parenthesis, like `foo.(123)`
3. `@nav.foo(binding)`, really? What's the (supposed) type of `@nav`? Does that type have the instance method `foo`?
4. `<%= foo %>` won't execute `foo`, because it's a local variable, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it renders `a..z` is because the [`Range#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-each) method (called from within the lambda) executes a given block for each element and then returns the range itself again.

What you would want to use here instead is the [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method.  Similar to `#each` it also executes a block for each element, but the return values of said block are returned in a new array.

For comparison:

```
p ("a".."c").each { |x| x.upcase }
#=> "a".."c"

p ("a".."c").map  { |x| x.upcase }
#=> ["A", "B", "C"]
```